# Tag synonyms for exegesis

Tags: discussion

I see we have tags for exegesis, interpretation, and meaning. It seems that one would suffice--I suggest exegesis as it is the least ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

I agree on exegesis being the canonical tag. Most of the questions tagged meaning and interpretation can be merged into exegesis. Caleb, though, has two unusual questions that wouldn't fit under exegesis:

Interpretation:
[What does it mean that "Scripture interprets Scripture"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79/what-does-it-mean-that-scripture-interprets-scripture)

Meaning:
[Whose meaning are we trying to find?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34/whose-meaning-are-we-trying-to-find)

Maybe we can re-tag these to something else?

Comment: I think those can probably be tagged something else. Those were pretty early in the game and there wasn't much to choose from and I had to tag with something! I'm inclined to think exegesis would not be a useful tag for those however.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, what are the guidelines on tags that are directly related to the topic of the site? If 50%+ of the questions on the site are related to exegesis, do we even want a tag at all?

Comment: You don't want tags that are on 100% or 90% of questions. Is there a consistent way you can break exegesis down so that questions would ALWAYS warrant one of the more specific tags covering exegesis?